# Revision control and updating 3rd party software - best practices

Tags: git

When updating 3rd party libraries to new versions (in this case embedded radio sw stacks written in C) I am having a hard time figuring out how to best "automatically" update these when an application is managed in a Git repo. File names might have changed, some files included in the library might contain changes needed by the application etc.

What is a good way to handle these kind of situations? Currently working with the Bluetooth Low Energy stack from Texas Instruments.

My initial thought was to create a patch from the current application state, extract the new library version and apply the patch on top of the updated "un-touched" library and fix any conflicts when applying the patch manually but there will be tons. Another thought was trying to find a C-aware plugin of some kind to use when merging but I haven't found what I think is a good solution yet.

Comment: I don't see what else you could do but create a branch, throw out the old stack, toss in the new one, fix everything... It isn't really clear if you mean to make changes inside the stack itself or not.

Comment: Yes, often modifications are needed to the stack source as APIs to all needed functionality for a more complex application don't exist.

Comment: In that case, and if it is to be used by several applications, it might make sense to store it in a different repo.

Answer (score 0):

This tasks aren't area of responsibility for VCS per se (it's part of Configuration Management duty), but... you can try to play with Git in this game

**If upstream's code is also versioned** and you can use it's repo**, you can (short draft):

- add new remote to your repo
- link this remote with special branch (different from your current work)
- fetch new version(s) from upstream
- merge to your branch|resolve conflicts|test

Comment: The software is delivered as a windows installer with the stack, helper functionality and usage examples. Makes it a bit hard to maintain an application on top of it.